# Can I use of "Good time" as "Good morning or Good afternoon"?

Tags: meaning

Can I use of "Good time" as "Good morning or Good afternoon" while I send a message for a person that I don't know, when he or she will see my message?

Comment: "Good time" does [have a meaning in English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good-time), but this isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Nobody uses “Good time” as a greeting like “Good morning” or “Good afternoon”. If you are trying to avoid being too specific (morning/afternoon), you could say “Good day” instead.

Comment: Or g'day if you are antipodean?

Comment: @BoldBen - Antipodean.  New word. Thanks for adding the new word to my vocabulary. One thing I never understood is why Aussies call everyone their mate (“G’day mate”). Sounds like an adventurous frame of mind. Where do I sign up?

Comment: Of course, we are all antipodean to somewhere, it just might not be a place with land and people.

Comment: @Spagirl - Hey, didnt you just school me on the doc handwriting question? Smart gal. I think I’m in love. Lol. Hopefully you weren’t the sole downvote on my lie/lay/lied question I posted earlier.

Comment: @Spagirl That's very true. I was using the word in its imperialist, blinkered, jingoistic, UK-centric sense. That's 'cos I'm British, old and have a sense of irony.

Comment: @BoldBen I’m also British and not in the first flush. Not sure I get your point in irony, I was only chipping in a bit more info on a word for someone who was new to it. I wasn’t trying to correct you in any way.

Comment: @Spagirl No worries (to follow the antipodean theme) that's the trouble with text of various descriptions, no subtlety of expression. I thought I was being funny and just funny and turned out odd!

Comment: @BoldBen That's a bonzer reply, mate! ;-)